# Google Cloud Functions Quickstart

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm having a very tough time getting started with Google Cloud functions.
In specific, making a simple HTTP POST Request.

The Cloud Function looks like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const errorhandler = require('errorhandler')
const logger = require('morgan')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')

let app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(logger('dev'))
app.use(errorhandler())
app.use(cors({origin: true}))

exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  // Example input: {"message": "Hello!"}
  if (req.body.message === undefined) {
    // This is an error case, as "message" is required.
    res.status(400).send('No message defined!');
  } else {
    // Everything is okay.
    console.log(req.body.message);
    res.status(200).send('Success: ' + req.body.message);
  }
};
```

I'm making the HTTP Request from a simple form HTML file, and a JS file that looks like:

```
const sendMessage = () => {



    const input = {
        "message" : document.getElementById('message').value
    }


    fetch('https://google-cloud-url-endpoint', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(input)
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
    }).then(function(data) {

    })
}
```

After typing in a message in the HTML Form, the console says:

OPTIONS https://https://google-cloud-url-endpoint 400 ()
index.html:1 Failed to load https://google-cloud-url-endpoint: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:53922' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

When inspecting the Network Response, I see:

No message defined!

So from what I understand, it's making the request and bringing a response from the function. My question is, how come it's not successfully sending the 'message' to the function?

Comment: Update: On this app called Postman, I set the request to POST, entered the URL, and defined {"message":"Hello There!"} and it successfully posted via the app.....I copied the code straight from the app and put it in my js file and it still says the same thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

Here's my client JS code:

```
function sendMessage() {

var message = document.getElementById('message').value

var data = JSON.stringify({
  "message": message
});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "https://us-central1-stripe- 
update.cloudfunctions.net/function-1");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");


xhr.send(data);
}
```

Here's The Google Cloud Functions code:

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  // Example input: {"message": "Hello!"}

  //set JSON content type and CORS headers for the response
    res.header('Content-Type','application/json');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

    //respond to CORS preflight requests
    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.status(204).send('');
    }

  if (req.body.message === undefined) {
    // This is an error case, as "message" is required.
    res.status(400).send('No message defined!');
  } else {
    // Everything is okay.
    console.log(req.body.message);
    res.status(200).send('Success: ' + req.body.message);
  }
};
```